# How to connect monero-wallet-rpc with my local node?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc

My monero node is fully synced. I'm using Ubuntu. In my monero config file I added:

```
Rpc-bind-ip=127.0.0.1
Rpc-bind-port=18081
Rpc-login=myusername:my password
```

Then I started monero with `./monerod`.

On another terminal I started:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18084 --wallet-file "wallet name " --password "my password" --daemon-address 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-login username: password
```

(with password from monero conf)

It gives me errors like

```
E client has incorrect username/password for server requiring authentication
E throw exception:tools:error: no connection to Daemon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Rpc-...` should be `rpc-...` (i.e. not capitalized)
2. `./monero-wallet-rpc ... --password "my password"` password here is your *wallet* password, not the password you have set for the daemon RPC. For that you need to use `./monero-wallet-rpc --daemon-login user:pass`.
3. `./monero-wallet-rpc ...--daemon-address 127.0.0.1` should be `--daemon-address 127.0.0.1:18081`, or simply `--daemon-host 127.0.0.1`, or even simpler, remove all settings specifying `127.0.0.1` or `18081` (in both wallet and daemon conf), as they are the *defaults* for the daemon RPC.

All of the options are documented in:

```
monerod --help
monero-wallet-rpc --help
```

Comment: After adding --daemon-login user:pass , it's working now . One more thing... With 127.0.0.1  can I access it from different locations ? Or do I need to change it ?

Comment: "One more thing... With 127.0.0.1 can I access it from different locations ?" - 127.0.0.1 is localhost only.